# How to specify custom mouse cursor with JSX style

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I specify a custom mouse cursor using a JSX inline style?

This works fine:

```
<Component
 style={{ cursor: 'crosshair' }}
/>
```

but I cannot seem to get anything along the lines of

```
<Component
 style={{ cursor: 'url(images/special.cur)' }}
/>
```

to work.  Elsewhere I am successfully getting static images from the same location

```
<img
 src="images/example.png"
/>
```

so I believe the server is set up properly.

I've tried Chrome, Firefox, and IE 11.

I know must be doing something fundamentally wrong.  How do I do this?

Thanks very much!

**EDIT**

(StackOverflow seems not to approve of the continued comment thread so let me address Josh's latest point as an edit instead.)

Yes, a plain HTML element gets the custom cursor.  I agree it must be a syntax problem, but what is the *correct* syntax for `cursor: url(file)` in JSX?  That is what I'm trying to figure out.  Thanks again!

```
<body>
    <input style="cursor: url(images/special.cur),auto;" type="img" src="images/example.png" />    
    <div id="container"></div>
...
</body>
```

where the `<input>` gets my special cursor and the "container" `<div>` is where my React components are rendered.

I also realize that I hadn't mentioned before that I am using React-Bootstrap components for my interface.  I know that Bootstrap adds lots of styles but I wouldn't think they would "win" in this case, would they?

Comment: What is the output in the DOM?

Comment: I just see the default cursor.  By the way, I see no errors from the developer console in the browsers I've tried and no errors from babelify.

Comment: No, I meant what do you see on the DOM element? What does the `style` property look like?

Comment: Oh, I see.  Using Chrome, I see `cursor: auto;` for the `<input>` element that React builds in the DOM.  FWIW, I see `cursor: "url(images/special.cur)"` among the props of the React component using the React developer window.  However, using Firefox, I actually see `cursor:url(images/special.cur)` in the DOM inspector.

Comment: I think you need to provide a fallback value, if I'm reading [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) right. Try `url(images/special.cur), auto` instead.

Comment: I tried adding `,auto` but it didn't change anything.  I did notice that the Styles tab in the "Elements" display of the Chrome dev tool window has a little amber "caution" triangle next to `cursor` that says "invalid property value" (with or without `,auto`).  How can I find out more?  In IE, the `url(images/special.cur)` has a squiggly red underline leading me to believe that the browsers agree there's a syntax problem.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Does anyone know of a small React/JSX example app or tutorial that uses a custom cursor?  I couldn't find any.

Comment: Based on what you've stated, I highly doubt this has anything to do with React because the style ends up on the rendered DOM component - it's just syntactically incorrect. Try it in your HTML file without React and I'm betting you'll see the same result.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I figured this out.  There were two things wrong, and Josh pointed one of them out.  Sorry if anyone wasted much time on this, but for the record:

The basic problem is that I used an online image converter to convert an image to .cur format and I now believe it returns corrupt or at least inadequate .cur files.

When I tried .png format instead *with a fallback value* as Josh suggested, I can make custom cursors work on Chrome and Firefox.  I will have to find some better tool to make a proper .cur file for IE still as it only supports the .cur (and .ani) formats.  I was able to use another .cur file I found online somewhere which does work with IE as documented.

[I know that I said I was able to use my "inadequate" .cur file with plain HTML outside of React; I must have been trying too many things at once.  Today I can't make that work either.  Sorry for the misleading reply.]

So JSX doesn't require anything special other than a valid cursor image file and a fallback built-in cursor.

```
<Component
 style={{ cursor: 'url(images/special.png),auto' }}
/>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who finds this off Google, here is everything you need to do:

- Put the cursor image in your **public** (not src) folder
- Add `style={{cursor: 'url(cursor.png),auto'}}` to your component

Full example:

```
public/
- cursor.png
- 404.html
- favicon.ico
- etc
src/
- App.js
```

App.js:

```js
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{cursor: 'url(cursor.png), auto'}}>
      Mouse over me for your custom cursor!
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Another issue that someone could face - is the dimension of the cursor image. I was using a 154x154 image but it didn't work. But I resized it to 64x64 it worked with this method. (Edit - it also works with 128x128 px)